# atomic behavior between kernel and user space in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, synchronization

I wonder that anyway to keep atomic behavior between kernel and user space?

For example with dm-thin:

one user space program ask thin device alloc block and tell program "OK".

Now power-off happened after alloc block and didn't tell program "OK".

Program will ask thin device alloc again, and kernel will waste a alloced block before because program didn't know it alloced once.

so is there anyway to make the behavior atomic? or any design pattern suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Every interaction from userspace to kernel goes thru a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)).

From the userland point of view, a system call is (by definition) atomic. Of course it could fail (see [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)).

I guess that the [device mapper](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/thin-provisioning.txt) could (or perhaps should) interact with [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

Comment: what kind of syscall help me?I found no one to apply in my scenario